# Why Highlight.js doesn't work after redirect?

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlight.js

I have made a mini application to describe the issue, i am trying to use highlight.js to highlight some code. The issue is when i press the navigate button from site1 it navigates me to site2 but the highlight wont apply, same thing happen if i go from site2 to site1, but if i refresh on any page it works rust fine.

I need to use navigate because with it i wont lose the values of variables.

**testr.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testr',
  templateUrl: './testr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testr.component.css']
})
export class TestrComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
  }

  clickme(){
    this.router.navigate(['/teste']);
  }

}
```

**testr.html**

```
<p>testr works!</p>
<pre><code>var char; alert(1+1)</code></pre>
<button (click)="clickme()" value="Link">Link</button>
```

**teste.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teste',
  templateUrl: './teste.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teste.component.css']
})
export class TesteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    hljs.initHighlighting();
  }

  clickme(){
    this.router.navigate(['/testr']);
  }
}
```

**teste.html**

```
<p>teste works!</p>
<pre><code>var char; alert(1+1)</code></pre>
<button (click)="clickme()" value="Link">Link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Highlight.js can't highlight code that doesn't exist when the "onload" event fires.  I'd guess that only your first view actually exists (when the page loads) and your second is only added to the actual DOM when you "visit" the second page.

After switching pages you'd need to call `initHighlighting` manually to highlight any new code blocks that have now been added to the page.